# How can I run multiple test fixtures in parallel using Selenium/NUnit?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, nunit

I have a bit of a problem. I am working on an automation project and I'm trying to execute a test on multiple browsers in parallel.

I have these 2 classes:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(EdgeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
public class BaseTest<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    protected IWebDriver _driver;

    [SetUp]
    protected void SetUp()
    {
        _driver = new TWebDriver();
    }

    [TearDown]
    protected void TearDown()
    {
        _driver?.Close();
    }
}

public class GoogleTest<TWebDriver> : BaseTest<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    [Test]
    public void NavigateToGoogle()
    {
        // Navigate
        _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

And I know I should add [Parallelizable] somewhere... but don't know where. I tried both placing it above the BaseTest class and above NavigateToGoogle method but it doesn't work either way. Does somebody have any idea? Or maybe I do something wrong the way I created these classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [Parallelizable] uses ParallelScope.Self as the scope. This means that the test will be able to run in parallel with *other* tests. Since there's only 1 test, it will execute synchronously.

Try changing the scope to Fixtures:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(EdgeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

You can see the different scopes and their meaning here: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/parallelizable.html

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. With this change it works. But I have one question: if by default [Parallelizable] uses ParallelScope.Self as the scope. then why is it not working when used for the fixture? I mean, in this case, "self" would be the fixture itself and [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] can just be [Parallelizable] (in your response). Is my reasoning a bit off? 

Comment: I think the key here is "other" tests. So by marking the fixture as self, the individual tests can't run in parallel with itself.